# WPF Combobox binding: remembers last value instead of displaying null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I want to use a ComboBox to show Contact3, or blank if Contact3 is null.

My ViewModel has a CurrentSample property which is the DataContext for a stack panel containing the controls below.

When CurrentSample.Contact3 != null the binding works fine.

When CurrentSample changes to a Sample with Contact3==null, the TextBox binding works fine but the ComboBox remembers the last non-null value.

I tried to create a simple example to demonstrate the behaviour but that worked fine! In my simple example, when CurrentSample.Contact3==null, the combo box is blank.

My full program is using EF proxies. When it's about to go wrong, the binding output makes a point of telling me that my DataObject is a proxy.

I've tried making OurPeople2 a collection and a CollectionViewSource, and with and without a null entry.

Remember, only YOU can save this project from (another) ugly kludge... nick (in .Net 4.5)

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Contact3.Surname, Mode=OneWay}"/>

<ComboBox 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main.OurPeople2}"
     SelectedItem="{bindings:ChilliBinding Path=Contact3}"
     DisplayMemberPath="Surname"
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

OK. The problem was this. ChilliBinding is a convenience class including several parameters.

```
public class ChilliBinding:Binding
{

    public ChilliBinding():base()
    {
        Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay;
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        NotifyOnValidationError = true;
        TargetNullValue = "";
    }
}
```

TargetNullValue lets users provide an empty string in text boxes to specify a null value. Doesn't work with a CombobBox. Perhaps the binding tries to translate a null value in the viewmodel into "", and then can't find that value in the combobox.

I've introduced a new convenience class ChilliBindingForCombo which leaves TargetNullValue unset. BTW to set the value of the combo to null, I don't need to have an empty value in the combobox, because I have a UserControl that includes a label, the combo box, and a "set combo to null" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FallbackValue` like this: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Contact3.Surname, Mode=OneWay}, FallbackValue={x:Null}"/>`

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. BTW the CollectionViewSource.CurrentItemChanged handler is not being called so it's not even getting as far as telling the combo box to change it's item. I also have a "Set Contact 3 to null" button. This does change the property, the TextBox updates, but not the combo box.

Comment: AAGH. I was using TargetNullvalue in my ChilliBinding. That allows users to clear the values in text boxes but doesn't seem to work for combo boxes. Thanks for taking an interest, that prompted me to look even more carefully...

Comment: Nice! Better than just showing you how to do it, is you doing it yourself!